# Why can't we store addresses in normal int variables? and by assigning i dont want it to point anywhere.

Tags: c, pointers

This is my basic c code. Just want to know about the why we need pointer variable even if we dont want to point.I know without pointing it to a variable would make it unusable. Still for the sake of understanding. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int i;
    int *j;
    i = 3;
    printf("%d\n", i);
    printf("%d\n", &i);
    j = &i;
    printf("%d\n", j);
}
```

// Inner working of pointers that why we cant use i = &j where i is just a normal integer.

Comment: Pointer and integer are often different sizes.

Comment: [Probably worth mentioning `intptr_t`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/stdint.h.html) for cases where you do want to store a pointer in a signed integer.

Comment: See http://www.unix.org/version2/whatsnew/lp64_wp.html for a thorough discussion of various memory models. From this, [most] unix/posix/linux/bsd systems/compilers (i.e. non-Windoze systems/compilers) use either the LP32 or LP64 models (for 32 bit or 64 bit systems respectively), so a pointer can be contained in a `long`. So, use `long` and `%ld`. You can get fancy with `intptr_t` or `ptrdiff_t` but it's really not required if you stay off WinX (which uses LLP64)

Comment: Start with the Basics... A pointer is simply a normal variable that holds the *address of* something else as its value. In other words, a pointer *points to* the address where something else can be found. Where you normally think of a variable holding an immediate values, such as `int a = 5;`, a pointer would simply hold the address where `5` is stored in memory, e.g. `int *b = &a;`. It works the same way regardless what type of object the pointer points to. (a pointer, is just a pointer....) Since `int *j;` declares `j` as a pointer to `int`, `&j` is the address of that pointer.

Comment: @CraigEstey too bad comments cannot be downvoted, because if they were, I'd do it right now.

Comment: Also, you cannot print the pointer value with `%d`. Cast to `(void*)` and print with `%p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why we need pointer variables...

No, we don't need pointer variables until... we need one. In other words, there are many cases (or algorithms) which don't need pointers. But soon or later you realize that pointers are needed.

Well, pointers contain values, which are different from integers, different from floating point numbers and so on. Even the space needed to hold such values can vary (an integer can take only 2 bytes, a float need more). An integer contains an (uh...) integer number, and only you (the programmer) know whether that number is correct or wrong. And a pointer contains an address and, again, only you know if that address is "correct" or not. A pointer "points" somewhere, there is nothing to do about it. There is an exception - normally, the value 0 or NULL is considered to "point nowhere", but it is just an accepted convention.

That said, many languages do actually permit you to store a pointer into an integer variable or even stranger assignments, but the compiler, which already knows little about your intentions, in this case does know even less than before; so you have to force the compiler, for example using type casting, as you see in the other answer, and you must know what you are doing. A typical problem is, as already said in the comments, that sometimes pointers need more bytes than integers. It is the same scenario about converting a floating number to an integer: you know you will lose something (decimals, in this case). It happens that, if an integer variable has enough space (bytes for representing it), everything goes smoothly and you can store a pointer into an int, and back again; addresses are, in effect, integer values. But why you should do that? Only because your algorithm manages data coming out from something  else than your program, for example a stream from outside world (data packets). Apart from this case, there are elegant (and correct) ways to keep well separated integers, and pointers, and mix them when needed (rarely).

Answer (score 1):

You can:
    int address=(int)&pointer;

But some computers are 32 bit and some 64 bit so the address size varies.

A pointer is just an address anyway.

Comment: Pointers are not necessarily **just** addresses. Flat address spaces are common today, but pointers can be segment IDs and offsets, word addresses plus sub-word information, and more. Two pointers to the same object can have different values when converted to integer.