# Why it becoming an error when we declare an integer pointer variable as integer variable?

Tags: c, pointers, integer

If a pointer "p" holds the address of a variable "a". if a=12 ( just taking an integer ) . If the address of "a" is 1024 (just an assumption for asking my doubt). That means the value in "p" is 1024. This 1024 is address but it is basically a number . Then why it doesn't work when we declare the integer pointer variable "p" as  integer variable "p". like:

```
int p, a=12;
p=&a;
printf("value of a is : %d", *p );
```

Comment: If you declare a variable as an `int`, then it's not a pointer, is it?  Just change it to `int *p`.  That will declare it to be a *pointer* to an `int`.  It's a simple bug, that's all.  So, fix it.  If you want to *force* a pointer value into an `int` variable, you can always cast it to `int`, but note that, on most 64-bit systems, a pointer is 64 bits while an int is 32 bits, so in general you will not be able to represent the entire pointer value.

Comment: `int p, a=12;` -> `int *p, a=12;` or better, `int *p; int a=12;`

Comment: my friend..,
I know that...but I like to know why this error is happening. An address (like 1024 as I mentioned in question) is a number .isn't it? p=&a is storing a address (which is a number). That means p contains an address but it is also an integer right? *p means the to take data from the place which p stores. Now p contains 1024 (if we declare p as integer 1024 in p is a integer number) . so it should work .right? I know that it wouldn't work. But y?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't we store addresses in normal int variables? and by assigning i dont want it to point anywhere.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50980121/why-cant-we-store-addresses-in-normal-int-variables-and-by-assigning-i-dont-wa)

Comment: _everything_ in a computer is a number or a string of numbers. The CPU has no concept of the "types" of numbers its operating on, and at that low level it doesn't matter. Different types and the data they represent is defined by the language (and enforced by the compiler) to provide order, organization, and ease of readability for humans. You're welcome to code in assembly if you want to bypass high level language constructs, but even there there are rules to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To declare `p` as a pointer to `int` do it the following way:

```
int *p; /* p is a pointer to int */
```

so, with initializers:

```
int a = 12, /* a is an integer var and it's initialized to 12 */
   *p = &a; /* p is an integer pointer and it's initialized to the addreess of a */
```

or as assignments:

```
a = 12; /* a is assigned the value 12 */
p = &a; /* p is assigned the address of a */
```

works, and `*p` will have the same value as `a`.

```
printf("value of a is : *p==%d (or what should be the same: a==%d)", *p, a);
```

Answer (score 2):

The example could be properly written (with some additional output) as:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
    intptr_t p;
    int a = 12;
    p = (intptr_t)(void *)&a;
    printf("value of a at %" PRIdPTR " is : %d\n", p, *(int *)(void *)p);
    return 0;
}
```

That relies on the following facts:

1. A pointer to any object can be converted to `void *` and back to a pointer to the original object type and it will compare equal to the original pointer to the object (so it will still point to it).
2. A pointer to `void` can be converted to a `intptr_t` or a `uintptr_t` value (by a cast operator) and back again and it will compare equal to the original pointer.
3. The `PRIdPTR` macro defined by `#include <inttypes.h>` expands to a string literal containing a printf conversion specifier (possibly preceded by a length modifier) suitable for printing the value of a parameter of type `intptr_t` as a signed decimal number. It is being included in the printf format string by string literal concatenation.

A `void *` pointer value is usually printed using the `%p` printf format, for example:

```
    printf("value of a at %p is : %d\n", (void *)p, *(int *)(void *)p);
```

or:

```
    printf("value of a at %p is : %d\n", (void *)&a, a);
```

Comment: nice, I didn't know that only `void*` can be legitly cast to `intptr_t`

Answer (score 0):

> *p means the to take data from the place which p stores.

The `*` operator when applied to an operand `p` basically means *"read what's on address stored in p **and interpret it as the type indicated by the pointer type p is declared as**"*

You're missing the last part. In your case, `p` is not a pointer, so the dereference operator does not make sense to use.